# Is there an easy way to Map properties on Socrata?

Tags: visualization, data-visualization, socrata, opendata

Since some of the open data has to do with property and each city has a unique identifier for a property, is there an easy way to map those unique identifiers in Socrata?

Visually, given a list of property unique identifiers in the open data, I'd like to see the properties on a map in one step.

[image: map of article 7 open petitions in nyc]

More examples: If you go to http://api.us.socrata.com/api/catalog/v1?column_names=bbl you will see hundreds of references because this is what New York City calls it's unique identifier for a property.

What would be helpful is if we could easily see these properties on a map.  We know that datasets should have latitude and longitude, but they usually do not.  Plus for a property it is better to see the outline of the property and not just a point on a map.

In order to make it easier to do this, there is a tool at https://map.tidalforce.org/ it allows you to paste a comma delimited NYC BBLs (borough, block and lot) list.  For example, https://map.tidalforce.org/?1pNFsY5rnHcsFEpLW2CJ   this maps the socrata dataset at https://data.cityofnewyork.us/City-Government/Open-Article-7-Petitions/aht6-vxai

Is there a way to integrate with Socrata to make it easier to map properties for each area, city, state, etc.  Or does this functionality already exist.

Comment: Are you interested in just mapping within the platform, such as [this tutorial](https://support.socrata.com/hc/en-us/articles/202950518-Make-classic-point-heat-and-boundary-maps) or are you wanting to join data like [the 311 calls you referenced](https://data.cityofnewyork.us/Social-Services/311-Service-Requests-from-2010-to-Present/erm2-nwe9/data) to the underlying property footprints?

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I did not mention 311 calls.  I was more interested in an easy way to go from open data with NYC unique identifiers (NYC calls them borough, block, and lot (BBL for short) to a map that shows the property outline.  I can easily do this with a little bit of bash scripting at https://map.tidalforce.org/ but it would be nice if it was built in to socrata.  I believe some mapping is, but not property specific mapping.  The reason is probably that it is very specific to the local government, but it would be a great thing for socrata to standardize and make it easier for us

Comment: I had been referring to the first link, which was data from 311 calls, but I see you are using that to reference BBL...for the shape outline, no, unfortunately there isn't a way to do that within Socrata.

Comment: Hi @TomSchenkJr Yes the first link is just the socrata way to scan all the catalogs across all the socrata instances to look for something.  In my case, I'm looking for BBL and 311 data happens to be the first link.  That is only random.  The point is there are many datasets that have BBL but no way to easily map them.

Comment: Thanks @TomSchenkJr but is there a way to build a plugin that socrata or a user could install.  I did not find a plugin framework, but maybe I missed it.

Comment: No, I don't think there would be a way to do that. There is some beta work they are doing for joining data via APIs (e.g., joining BBLs) but that is not fully released yet and wouldn't work with property outlines/footprints.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/173686/discussion-between-ralph-yozzo-and-tom-schenk-jr).